# Can't create schema on initialize-database if hsqlbd is on server-mode

Tags: java, spring, initialization, hsqldb

I have Hsqldb 1) in memory

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="idtSimulatorDataSource" type="HSQL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:hsql/idt_schema.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
```

2) on server-mode

```
<bean id="idtSimulatorDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/idt_simulatordb"/>
    </bean>
```

1) all works properly
2) can't create schema. If I create schema manually, then hibernate create all necessary DDL manipulations and everethyng works properly too.
But I don't know where should I assign property for db initialization script

Here are my persistence file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="IDTSimulator" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTAccount</class>
        <class>com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTCard</class>
        <class>com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTCurrency</class>
        <class>com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTCardHolder</class>
        <class>com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTProgram</class>
        <class>com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTTransaction</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <!-- -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="simulators"/>
            <!-- -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <!-- -->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="10"/>


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here are my init file script

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS simulators CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA SIMULATORS AUTHORIZATION SA -- not work yet
CREATE TABLE SIMULATORS.dirtyhack();
```

Maybe it would be better to create schema automatically, but I don't know how

**UPDATE**
I've founf how to launch db init script:

> jdbc:initialize-database data-source="idtSimulatorDataSource">

Also I set

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

But now I've got following error:

```
11:15:57,337  WARN (main) [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
11:15:57,370 ERROR (main) [JDBCExceptionReporter] user lacks privilege or object not found: IDT_CARD
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzala/rzalastc.html

```
SQLSTATE Value:      42501  
Meaning: The authorization ID does not have the privilege to perform the specified operation on the identified object.
```

What are privileges ?????

**UPDATE:**
Now I'm really confused.
I look into log. And see following:

> /*C2*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS simulators CASCADE
>   CREATE SCHEMA SIMULATORS AUTHORIZATION SA CREATE TABLE
>   SIMULATORS.dirtyhack() DISCONNECT /*C3*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC DISCONNECT
>   /*C4*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS simulators CASCADE
>   CREATE SCHEMA SIMULATORS AUTHORIZATION SA DISCONNECT /*C5*/SET SCHEMA
>   PUBLIC DISCONNECT /*C6*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC

But I recently changed my init script:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS simulators CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA SIMULATORS AUTHORIZATION sa -- not work yet
CREATE TABLE SIMULATORS.dirtyhack1();
```

Where is my  **dirtyhack1** () table???
I deleted all mentions about previous launches

**UPDATE**

I've found the reason.
This block is executed after Hibernate create its DDL manipulations:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="idtSimulatorDataSource" type="HSQL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:hsql/idt_schema.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
```

And my code contains such lines:

```
public static Server server = new Server();

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown1() throws Exception {
        server.shutdown();
    }


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        HsqlProperties p = new HsqlProperties();
        p.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:./idt_simulatordb");
        p.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "idt_simulatordb");
        p.setProperty("server.port", "9001");
        server.setProperties(p);
        server.start();

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/idt_simulatordb", "sa", "");
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();    // statements
        String expression1 = "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS simulators CASCADE;\n";
        (1)String expression2 = "CREATE SCHEMA SIMULATORS AUTHORIZATION SA;";
        String expression3 = "CREATE TABLE SIMULATORS.dirtyhack1();";
        st.executeUpdate(expression1);    // run the query
        st.executeUpdate(expression2);    // run the query
        st.executeUpdate(expression3);    // run the query
        st.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

That's why I didn't find my dirtyhack1 table, and that's why I got error. Init-database just removed my simulators schema

So there is a question. How to launch init script before Hibernate? Cause if I wouldn't write line (1) then I get error about wrong schema export

Comment: One question: go one step back and ask yourself if you really want to execute a script that drops the database every time you start the sever?

Comment: well this is junit test. To be sure that I don't have any artifacts it's better to clear db and create it by Hibernate

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Spring [EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html) to create the database. Something like this:

```
new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().addScript("classpath:hsql/idt_schema.sql").build();
```

Then you don't need Hibernate to create the schema for you because it will already exist.